# tell protractor to block on asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm adding a fresh, angular client-tier to a legacy app. Upon login the legacy up redirects to a 'home' url. The url contains a session id which I need to grab and use (in the url) for any subsequent gets/posts. After login I call:

```
browser.getCurrentUrl()
```

and then use a regex to extract the session id. I store the session id away and use it for later gets/posts.

The problem is though that browser.getCurrentUrl() returns a promise and all my tests run before I can get the session id back. How can I make protractor wait for the browser.getCurrentUrl() to resolve.

Specifically below where I have the code:

```
var sessionId = loginPage.login('testuser@example.com', 'testuser');
homePage = new HomePage(sessionId);
```

I really need all code to block on loginPage.login() so I'll have a defined session id. My home page tests and any other page tests will need the session id to run properly.

How can I achieve this in protractor?

Thanks!

The relevant parts of my code looks like this...

home.spec.js:

```
describe('home page tests', function() {
  var loginPage = new LoginPage();
  var homePage;

  // get sessionId from login and create a new HomePage object from it
  beforeEach(function() {
    var sessionId = loginPage.login('testuser@example.com', 'testuser');
    homePage = new HomePage(sessionId);
    homePage.get();
  });

  describe('main elements of home page test', function() {    
    it('page has correct username as part of user menu', function() {
      expect(homePage.getUsername()).toEqual('testuser@example.com');
    });
  });
});
```

login.po.js:

```
function LoginPage {

  // ...snip...

  this.login = function(username, password) {
    return this.get()
      .then(function() {
        this.username.sendKeys(username);
        this.password.sendKeys(password);

        this.loginButton.click();
      })
      .then(function() {
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
          var groups = sessionIdRegex.exec(url);

          // return the extracted session id or null if there is none
          if (groups !== null) {
            return sessionIdRegex.exec(url)[2];
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        });
      });
  };
}
```

home.po.js:

```
function HomePage(sessionId) {
  this.username = element(by.binding('username'));

  this.getUsername = function() {
    return this.username.getText();
  }

  this.get = function() {
    return browser.get(browser.baseUrl + sessionId + '#/home');
  };
};

module.exports = HomePage;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest could be to use [`expect`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/9e5d9e4abb7d0928e6092a711fda527554994be7/docs/control-flow.md#protractor-adaptations):

> Jasmine expectations are also adapted to understand promises. That's why the line
>
> `expect(name.getText()).toEqual('Jane Doe');
>
> works - this code actually adds an expectation task to the control flow, which will run after the other tasks.

login.po.js:

```
function LoginPage {

  this.login = function(username, password) {
    return this.get()
      .then(function() {
        this.username.sendKeys(username);
        this.password.sendKeys(password);

        this.loginButton.click();
      })
      .then(function() {
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
          var groups = sessionIdRegex.exec(url);

          // return the extracted session id or null if there is none
          if (groups !== null) {
            return sessionIdRegex.exec(url)[2];
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        });
      });
  };
  expect(this.login).not.toBeUndefined();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I couldn't get this to work at all. browser.driver.wait() just returned immediately regardless of whether isPending returned true or false.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how jasmine has been adapted to understand promises. The problem was I was not trying to test/expect anything about the return value of login (I do that in other tests), what I'm trying to do is actually use the returned session id in subsequent gets. For example from the home.po.js: return browser.get(browser.baseUrl + sessionId + '#/home'); Here I need sessionId to be resolved. I eventually get around this by changing the get method to look like:     sessionIdPromise.then(function(sessionId) {return browser.get(browser.baseUrl + '1:' + sessionId + '#/home');});